# Get Apache Cordova Working On Visual Studio 2017

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova

The sample project with no changes fails to build on VS2017 on my installation. (e.g. file new apache cordova app... then run)

I am using VS within VMWARE, but that shouldn't make a difference.  I get **different errors** running the project.  e.g. I run and get:

```
2>assert.js:90
2>throw new assert.AssertionError({
2>**Node process unexpectedly exited while waiting for property 'appUrl'.**
2>assert.js:90
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

And then with no changes, if I run again I sometimes get a missing path error instead.

```
assert.js:90
throw new assert.AssertionError({
AssertionError: missing path
at Module.require (module.js:351:3)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\MDA\cb54b8fa\taco-toolset-6.3.1\simulate.js:15:13)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
at startup (node.js:139:18)
at node.js:968:3
```

This happens when I try the simulare in browser option from the build menu.
I can't seem to find a solution for this.  I have tried

1. Clearing the cordova cache from visual studio tools -> options menu
2. Reinstalling and/or parts of visual studio including the taco tools
3. Upgrading VS 2017 to latest release
4. Repairing the visual studio installation completely
5. Upgrading VMWARE to latest patches (I was desperate)

If i try the Google Emulator - Phone build option, then I get a different error

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Error: Target 'Phone_armeabi-v7a_ToolsForApacheCordova' not found, unable to run project    BlankCordovaApp4

At wits end, how can I get this to work?  What path could it be mising?  I can't even find a modules.js file on my hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution.  Using the visual studio installer I installed node.js option.  Shouldn't need to as it is a seperate dependancy and node.js is installed anyway when you install the mobile development option.. but for whatever reason that solved this issue, looks like VS just got in a tailspin despite reinstalling mobile development and also fully re-pairing the entire vs install.. :(